# mainly between 1862 and 1878

Tags: grammar

> Amish Mennonites came into existence through reform movements among North American Amish **mainly between 1862 and 1878**.

Source https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amish_Mennonite

---

Did Amish Mennonites come into existence mainly between 1862 and 1878 or did reform movements among North American Amish happen mainly between 1862 and 1878?
What does "**mainly between 1862 and 1878**" modify?

Comment: It's an adjunct of time functioning as a modifier in clause structure. In other words, it modifies the whole of the sequence _Amish Mennonites came into existence through reform movements among North American Amish_.

Comment: I think the sentence is badly written; the _people_ didn't come into existence then, but the group which took on that name. A later paragraph explains that the split came about as a result of conferences held between those dates.

Comment: I think the construction is inherently ambiguous, but the *default* (which *appears* to make sense) is that the referent of the ***mainly-*** clause is the nearest credible preceding element (***reform movements***, here). But of course, we could "sidestep" the ambiguity (such as it is) by assuming that both the Mennonites ***and*** the reforms came about simultaneously.

Comment: The most natural interpretation is that the reform movements created the Mennonites in the course of their reforms, at the same time or shortly after. If the reform movements only created Mennonites much later, it would be more natural to say something like "Amish Mennonites came into existence in the 1920s from reform movements among North American Amish which had occurred mainly between 1862 and 1878."

Comment: Answering without knowing external information is impossible. The sentence is ambiguous.

Comment: at least one way of looking at it: If A caused B, at a certain time, then it doesn't particularly matter if the dates (1862 and 1878) refer to A, or B, or both.  The results are the same. Of course, excluding the interpretation "the *people* didn't come into existence then".